# MS Access Two tables return records where value from Table 1 found in more than one column table 2

Tags: ms-access

I can't seem to figure out the below using MS Access.

Summary is that I have Two tables. I would like to compare column E in table to column A, B, or C and return the records on table1 where the values match. Basically the criteria to match (table2.column E) can be in more than one the columns in table1.

Ex. 
Table1

Column A | Column B | Column C

Dan   Stan        XXX

David       XXX         XXX

Roger       XXX         XXX

Ricco       XXX         XXX

Wilbert     XXX        Dingo

Table2

Column D | Column E | Column F

1          Roger      North

2          Stan       South

3          Michael    South

4          Colo       East

5          Kanye      East

6          Dingo      West

Return

Column A | Column B | Column C | Column F

Dan         Stan        XXX       South

Roger       XXX         XXX       North

Wilbert     XXX        Dingo      West

I have tired below below SQL string in MS Access (2013)

SELECT table1.*
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.column E = table1.[column A] 
OR table2.column E = table1.[column B] OR table2.column E = table1.[column C];

I don't get an error but something is seriously wrong - queries on this DB usually take 20-40 seconds (tops) (3 million records - linked tables to MS SQL Server 2016) - the query has been going for 40 minutes. When I view the table view in MS Access itself it shows the records but the application keeps freezing and stuttering. I tried going to end of the records and I had to kill MS Access. Tried pulling the data into a Pivot in Excel and I have never seen the data pull so slowly (we are talking 50 records a minute).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a join clause can have OR operation. Also, need [ ] around [column E].

Try:

`SELECT table1.*, tabl2.columnF FROM table1, table2 WHERE [column e] = [column a] OR [column e] = [column b] OR [column e] = [column c];`